# Fixing this error "NoneType object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python, folium

Since days and days, I could not figure out this issue. I got this error

```
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable. 
lib/python3.8/site-packages/folium/features.py
```

The problem is at this point:

```
layer=folium.GeoJson(
            edges_gdf,
            tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['oneway','lanes',
            'length','speed','name'],localize=True),
            style_function=lambda x: {'color': line_color}).add_to(m)
```

Here is the full function:

```
def retrieve_data_from_postgres(network_id, Simple,
                          set_initial_crs=4326,
                          zone_radius=15,
                          intersection_radius_percentage=0.8,
                          distance_offset_percentage=0.8,
                          line_color='orange',
                          link_side='right',

                          ):
    initial_crs = "EPSG:{}".format(set_initial_crs)
    initial_crs = CRS(initial_crs)
    CRS84 = "EPSG:4326"
    default_crs = "EPSG:3857"

    edges = Edge.objects.filter(network_id=network_id)
    edges = serialize('geojson', edges,
        fields=('id', 'param1', 'param2', 'param3', 'speed', 'length',
        'lanes','geometry', 'name', 'source', 'target','network', 'road_type'))

    edges = json.loads(edges)
    edges_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_features(edges['features']) 

    nodes = Node.objects.filter(network_id=network_id).values()
    nodes_df = pd.DataFrame(nodes)
    nodes_df['location'] = nodes_df['location'].apply(geometry.Point)
    nodes_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(nodes_df, geometry=nodes_df['location'])

    edges_gdf.set_crs(initial_crs, inplace=True)
    nodes_gdf.set_crs(initial_crs, inplace=True)
    nodes_gdf.to_crs(CRS84, inplace=True)
    zone_radius = zone_radius
    intersection_radius = intersection_radius_percentage * zone_radius
    distance_offset = distance_offset_percentage * zone_radius
    tiles_layer = 'OpenStreetMap'

    edges_gdf["oneway"] = edges_gdf.apply(lambda x: not edges_gdf[
        (edges_gdf["source"] == x["target"]) & (edges_gdf["target"] == x["source"])
        ].empty, axis=1)

    edges_gdf.to_crs(crs=default_crs, inplace=True)

    col_list = ['geometry', 'oneway']
    edges_gdf['_offset_geometry_'] = edges_gdf[col_list].apply(
        lambda x: x['geometry'].parallel_offset(distance_offset, link_side) if not x['oneway']
        else x['geometry'].parallel_offset(0, link_side),axis=1)


    edges_gdf.drop('geometry', axis=1, inplace=True)
    edges_gdf.set_geometry('_offset_geometry_', inplace=True)
    edges_gdf.set_crs(default_crs, inplace=True)
    edges_gdf.to_crs(crs=CRS84, inplace=True)

    latitudes = list(nodes_gdf['geometry'].y)
    longitudes = list(nodes_gdf['geometry'].x)

    # Initialize the map
    m = folium.Map(location=[latitudes[0], longitudes[0]],
                   max_zoom=18, prefer_canvas=True, tiles=tiles_layer)

    layer=folium.GeoJson(
        edges_gdf,
        tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['oneway','lanes',
        'length','speed','name'],localize=True),
        style_function=lambda x: {'color': line_color}).add_to(m)
    m.fit_bounds(layer.get_bounds())

    # Adding the nodes points
    for lat, long in list(zip(latitudes, longitudes)):
        folium.Circle(location=[lat, long], color='cyan', fill=True,
            fill_opacity=1,radius=intersection_radius).add_to(m)

    m.save('templates/visualization.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
latitudes = list(nodes_gdf['geometry'].y)
longitudes = list(nodes_gdf['geometry'].x)

# Initialize the map
m = folium.Map(location=[latitudes[0], longitudes[0]],
               max_zoom=18, prefer_canvas=True, tiles=tiles_layer)

layer=folium.GeoJson(
    edges_gdf,
    tooltip=folium.GeoJsonTooltip(fields=['oneway','lanes',
    'length','speed','name'],localize=True),
    style_function=lambda x: {'color': line_color}).add_to(m)
m.fit_bounds(layer.get_bounds())
```

The error message is saying that you tried to use a `None` object as a list (or array), so the problem is unlikely to be on that line but above it somewhere. I would guess it is
the line that creates the `Map` and that either `latitudes` or `longitudes` (or both) are `None` for one of your geometries, which might be related to:

```
edges_gdf.drop('geometry', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: I don't think it is about the line initializing the map. I tested it without the layer object and it works fine. I try to convert the edges_df to geojson without success

Comment: Try printing out the lat and lon lists

Answer (score 2):

I got the same error in geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explore(), which uses the folium map. It appears that I had one row in which the geometry was POINT EMPTY instead of having the proper coordinates. After giving that point proper coordinates, everything works as it should.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving this here in case anyone else got the same error. There appears to be a bug in the Folium package itself. In my folium/features.py the function warn_for_geometry_collections(self) threw the TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable on the line `if feature['geometry']['type'] == 'GeometryCollection'` . For a quickfix you can comment out this line.

Comment: Filtering out rows with geometry None as Eemeli suggests works also.